# Zend _forward doesn't work after failed authentication (Zend Framework 1)

Tags: php, zend-framework

After a user fails authorisation I'd like to forward them back to the login page. Currently the _forward method causes Zend to hang and give a time out error (30 seconds exceeded).

The code for the login page handles both a login and signup form, and forwards to the authorisation controller:

```
public function indexAction() {

    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->_request->getPost();

        if (array_key_exists('signUp', $formData)) {
            $authAction = 'signup';
            $form = 'signupForm';
        } elseif (array_key_exists('logIn', $formData)) {
            $authAction = 'login';
            $form = 'loginForm';
        }

        if ($this->$form->isValid($formData)) {
            $this->_forward($authAction, 'user-auth', null, $formData);
        } else {
            $this->$form->populate($formData);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine and redirects to the auth controller successfully. The code inside the login action of the auth controller is as such:

```
public function loginAction() {
    $formData = $this->_request->getPost();

    $authAdapter = new My_Auth_Adapter();
    $authAdapter->setTableName('user')
                ->setIdentity($formData['username'])
                ->setCredential($formData['password'])
                ->setIdentityColumn('username')
                ->setCredentialColumn('password');
    $result = $authAdapter->authenticate();

    if ($result->isValid()) {
        // success, all good
    } else {
        $this->_forward('index', 'login', 'default', $formData);
    } 
}
```

We arrive here fine, and a successful authorisation works as expected. However in my else statement placing another forward back to the original login controller (I wish to populate the username as well as post back an error message) causes the program to hang, although a redirect works fine.

I thought it may be because the login controller is re-detecting the post data and I'm getting caught in an infinite loop, but removing the $formData as the last argument of the forward doesn't change anything.

I've also tried $formData['errMsg'] = 'whatever' above the forward and then checking if the key exists or if it is set in the login controller, but that doesn't change a thing either.

Interestingly, the time out error I receive references the Auth DbTable Adapter:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /Applications/MAMP/MampServer/mysite/library/Zend/Auth/Adapter/DbTable.php on line 174
```

Any ideas as to what may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are infinity looping between `loginAction()` and `indexAction()`.

Check out the difference between the calls to `forward()` and `redirect()` action helpers. The former, `forward()` internally will change the `$request->isDispatched() == false` - This means that the front controller will execute the targeted controller action *without* a new HTTP request.

The outcome of this is that `$this->_request->isPost()` will always be `true` and therefore `$this->$form->isValid($formData)` again will also be true, meaning your going around in circles.

I know the below is a very different to your approach, however I believe it is a more conventional separation of concerns for Zend 1 controllers.

```
// ... SomeController.php

  public function getLoginForm();

  public function getSignupForm();

  protected function authenticate($username, $password) 
  {
    $authAdapter = new My_Auth_Adapter();
    $authAdapter->setTableName('user')
                ->setIdentity($username)
                ->setCredential($password)
                ->setIdentityColumn('username')
                ->setCredentialColumn('password');
    $result = $authAdapter->authenticate();

    return ($result->isValid()) ? true : false;
  }

  public function indexAction()
  {
    $form = $this->getLoginForm();
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
      if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {

        if ($this->authenticate($form->getValue('username'), $form->getValue('username'))) {
          $this->redirect('/members'); // Successfully logged in
        }
      }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
  }

  public function signupAction()
  {
    // stuff only for signups! 
  }
```

**Edit** To elaborate: `forward()` is a controller action helper. Its job is simply to modify the `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` instance. The `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` class is the one returned when you call `$this->getRequest()` within a controller.

The Request instance encapsulates all access to `$_POST`, `$_GET` and stores then as values within the object. Calls such as `$request->setParam('someparam', 123)` set or get these values rather than the standard direct access to `$_POST['someparam']` or `$_GET['someparam']`.

The special case is with the values `module`,`controller`,`action` and `dispatched`. These are the key's used by the `Zend_Controller_Front` and the *Dispatcher* when trying to determine the correct controller to *instantiate* and action method to *execute*.

A simplified example of how the [**dispatch loop**](http://nethands.de/download/zenddispatch_en.pdf) works:

```
while(! $request->isDispatched()) {

  $request->setDispatched(true);

  // If at any point here we change setDispatched(true)
  // perhaps in a controller action with a call to forward()
  // then the whole dispatch loop will be called again
  // perhaps creating a different controller

  $controllerName = $request->getControllerName();
  $actionName = $request->getActionName();

  $controller = new $controllerName();
  $controller->$actionName();

}
```

Comment: THanks - this solution makes a lot more sense than how I was attempting to do it. One thing, however, if you could elaborate a little - I'm confused as to how you're able to attach parameters to the forward method if it doesn't reset HTTP headers? Or is it a once set, that's it kind of deal?

Comment: @AdrianNorman I've updated my answer with a bit more, I hope it makes sense. Best thing to do would be to look into the controller and dispatcher's code to get a better idea.

Comment: Thanks very much for the elaboration - cleared up a lot for me just in regards to the Zend_Controller_Request_Http object.

Answer (score 0):

In the else block:

```
$this->_redirect($this->url(array('login' => $formData['username'], 'nameOfYourRoute'));
```

Added a new get variable 'login' to your route and populate your forms login with this variable.